# How to clip an image for beamer hand-outs

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am using Beamer to produce slides.  Everything works fine but not for the hand-outs.  The problem is that the graphic file on the title page is larger than the page size.  How can this be fixed?  I tried to clip the image but I cannot make it work (see my code below).  Note that I do not want the change the size nor the aspect ratio of the input graphic (`\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}` is not what I am looking for).

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<handout>{%
  \usepackage{pgfpages}
  \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}


\title{My Title}


\begin{document}

{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
%      \path[clip] (0,0) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
      \node[opacity=.5,inner sep=0]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
  My second slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  My third slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  My fourth slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the output I wish for the handouts for the two first slides:

[image]

Comment: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1190

Comment: Works like a charm :)